# Custom dcasting via data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, dcast

Here is my data

```
dt = data.table(x=sample(8,20,TRUE), 
                y=sample(2,20,TRUE), 
                w = sample(letters[5:20], 20, TRUE),
                u = sample(letters[2:25], 20, TRUE),
                z=sample(letters[1:4], 20,TRUE), 
                d1 = runif(20), d2=runif(20))
```

Here is my dcasting code.

```
DC_1 = dcast.data.table(dt,x+w ~ z, value.var = "d1")
```

This works fine. However my data could also additionally include column 'a' and column 's' as shown below. Both of them could be included, either one, or none of them.

```
dt = data.table(x=sample(8,20,TRUE), 
                y=sample(2,20,TRUE), 
                w = sample(letters[5:20], 20, TRUE),
                u = sample(letters[2:25], 20, TRUE),
                z=sample(letters[1:4], 20,TRUE), 
                a = sample(letters[1:25], 20, T),
                s = sample(letters[2:17], 20, T),
                d1 = runif(20), d2=runif(20))
```

The additional columns however would always be **characters** . Also my data always has to be cast on column 'z' and value variable would always be 'd1'

How do I dcast via data.table such that it takes all the character columns (except z) available in the data table and casts them on z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could subset the dataset column and use `...` on the lhs of `~` to specify for all columns and on the rhs of formula it would be 'z'

```
dcast(dt[, setdiff(names(dt), 'd2'), with = FALSE], ... ~ z, value.var = 'd1')
```

---

Or get the column names of the character columns programmatically

```
nm1 <- dt[, names(which(unlist(lapply(.SD, is.character))))]
nm2 <- setdiff(nm1, 'z')
dcast(dt,paste0(paste(nm2, collapse="+"), "~ z"), value.var = 'd1')
```

---

Or another option is `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
dcast(dt[, select(.SD, where(is.character), d1)], ... ~ z, value.var = 'd1')
```

---

A similar option in `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyr)
dt %>% 
   select(where(is.character), d1) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = z, values_from = d1)
```

Comment: No @akrun. No duplicate elements, that was completely coincidental. Have made the column contents unique to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Manasi can you specify the `set.seed` and also your expecetd output

Comment: I have set the seed to 2. The expected formula that needs to run is `DC_1 = dcast.data.table(dt,x+w+a+s ~ z, value.var = "d1")` when a and s are also present.

Comment: There cant be a user intervention to subset as this is running as a part of a function. Is there any way it can subset all character columns except z?